# compare two file and find matching words in python

Tags: python, file, search

I have a two file: the first one includes terms and their frequency:

```
table 2
apple 4
pencil 89
```

The second file is a dictionary:

```
abroad
apple
bread
...
```

I want to check whether the first file contains any words from the second file. For example both the first file and the second file contains "apple".
I am new to python.
I try something but it does not work. Could you help me ? Thank you

```
for line in dictionary:
    words = line.split()
    print words[0]

for line2 in test:
    words2 = line2.split()
    print words2[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open("file1") as f1,open("file2") as f2:
    words=set(line.strip() for line in f1)   #create a set of words from dictionary file

    #why sets? sets provide an O(1) lookup, so overall complexity is O(N)

    #now loop over each line of other file (word, freq file)
    for line in f2:
        word,freq=line.split()   #fetch word,freq 
        if word in words:        #if word is found in words set then print it
            print word
```

**output:**

```
apple
```

Comment: If there are more than one matching terms this code does not work :(

Comment: @user9514870 that's beacause you said: *"I want to check whether the first file contains **any** words"*, you can remove the `break` statement to get all the common words.

Answer (score 3):

It may help you :

```
file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open('file1.txt'))

file2 = set(line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt'))

for line in file1 & file2:

    if line:

        print line
```

Comment: This is not going to work as one file contains words and other contains space separated values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should do:

- First, you need to put all the dictionary words in some place where you can easily look them up. If you don't do that, you'd have to read the whole dictionary file every time you want to check one single word in the other file.
- Second, you need to check if each word in the file is in the words you extracted from the dictionary file.

For the first part, you need to use either a `list` or a `set`. The difference between these two is that `list` keeps the order you put the items in it. A `set` is unordered, so it doesn't matter which word you read first from the dictionary file. Also, a `set` is faster when you look up an item, because that's what it is for.

To see if an item is in a set, you can do: `item in my_set` which is either True or False.

Answer (score 2):

I have your first double list in `try.txt` and the single list in `try_match.txt`

```
f = open('try.txt', 'r')
f_match = open('try_match.txt', 'r')
print f
dictionary = []
for line in f:
    a, b = line.split()
    dictionary.append(a)

for line in f_match:
    if line.split()[0] in dictionary:
        print line.split()[0]
```

Comment: @user951487 This complexity of this solution is `O(N^2)` solution while for my solution is `O(N)`.