# Search and replace between two files with search phrase in first file: Python

Tags: python, regex, string, match

File 1:

```
$def String_to_be_searched (String to be replaced with)
```

File 2:

```
..... { word { ${String to be searched} } # each line in File 2 is in this format
..... { word { ${String} } # This line need not be replaced. Only lines which matches the string in file 1 needs to be replaced
```

I want to replace the "String to be searched" in file 2 with "String to be replaced with" from file 1 once each line of file 2 has the "String to be searched" in it.

My Code:

```
def labelVal(line):
    return line[line.find('(') + 1: line.rfind(')')]

for line in File 1:
    Label = {}
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('$def'):
        labelKeys = line .split()[1]
        #print labelKeys
        labelValues = labelVal(line)
        #print labelValues
        Label[labelKeys] = labelValues
        #print Label
outfile = open('path to file','w')

for line in File 2:
    match = re.findall(r'\$\{(\w+)\}', line) # Here I am searching for the pattern ${String to be searched}
    if match:
        print match.group()
```

Output So Far:

I have the Label as a Dictionary with the String to be searched and the string to be replaced. I am first trying to match the string in both files then I have to replace. But The second part does not give me any match... I used [compare two file and find matching words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355137/compare-two-file-and-find-matching-words-in-python) this as a reference.

Comment: Is the `${String to be searched}` multiple words or one word because your regex currently limits to something like `${foo}`

Comment: SO it is mostly one word. Like : Foo or Foo_Bar ...

Comment: And you should loop: `for x in matches: print x`

Comment: Okay that prints out the matches. Now how do I replace just that string in the first line? Will line = line.replace(match, labelValues) work?

Comment: Do you want file2 to be exactly the same Except for the replaced strings?

Comment: Yes All the lines should be the same. And the string that matches with file 1 should be replaced by the replace string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "second part" - a regex isn't necessary to replace the text in `File 2`.  Just read the entire file and use the `str` method `replace`.

```
with open('tobefixed.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

for search_txt, replacement_txt in Label.iteritems():
    data = data.replace(search_txt, replacement_txt)

with open('fixed.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

If you want to use the `re` module, use `re.sub`:

```
for search_txt, replacement_txt in Label.iteritems():
    data = re.sub(search_txt, replacement_txt, data)
print data
```

---

For the "first part" - you create a new dictionary, `Label`, in every iteration of the `for` loop.  You should just create one dictionary with all the `defs` in it;

```
with open('defs.txt') as f:
    Label = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('$def'):
            labelKeys = line .split()[1]
            labelValues = labelVal(line)
            Label[labelKeys] = labelValues
```

Comment: When I try to print the searchtxt and replacement txt in the for loop, it does not print out.. IS it possible to call Label.iteritems() like how you have done??

Comment: @Doodle yes, see [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) in the Tutorial.

Comment: Creating the Label as one dict helped!! Thanks a lot .