# Reading and writing text files while checking occurrences

Tags: python

I'm trying to read names from a text file called `first-names.txt` and see if they exist in `oliver-twist.txt`.

So far I have been able to output the names to `occurrences.txt` that aren't in `oliver-twist.txt` but exist in `first-names.txt` with the following code.

```
with open('first-names.txt', 'r')as f:
    d = set(f.readlines())

with open('oliver-twist.txt', 'r') as f:
    e = set(f.readlines())

with open('occurrences.txt', 'a') as f:
    for line in list(d-e):
        f.write(line)
```

Snippet from `oliver-twist.txt`:

```
This resistance only infuriated Mr. Sikes the more; who, dropping on
his knees, began to assail the animal most furiously.  The dog jumped
from right to left, and from left to right; snapping, growling, and
barking; the man thrust and swore, and struck and blasphemed; and the
struggle was reaching a most critical point for one or other; when, the
door suddenly opening, the dog darted out:  leaving Bill Sikes with the
poker and the clasp-knife in his hands.
```

Snippet from `first-names.txt`:

```
Aaron
Aaron
Abbey
Abbie
Abby
Abdul
Abe
Abel
Abigail
Abraham
Abram
Ada
Adah
Adalberto
Adaline
Adam
Adam
Bill
```

The expected output should be:

```
Bill
```

because Bill is the only first name occurring in `oliver-twist.txt`.
How do I find the same occurrences rather than the differences in the files?

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: Updated, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compare two file and find matching words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355137/compare-two-file-and-find-matching-words-in-python)

Comment: This has been definitely asked before. If you search a bit you will find an answer :)

Comment: Since you have sets, I think you should be able to do an intersection with the `&` operator. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Yeah I've been searching for hours and nearly started using regex instead. Thanks guys, I'm still trying to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with open('first-names.txt') as f:
    first_names = f.readlines()

with open('oliver-twist.txt') as f:
    oliver_twist = f.read()

for name in first_names:
    if name in oliver_twist:
        print(name)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a comprehension over the two sets you imported from the text files, I added some more names to your sample to test, all names look to be detected.

Utilising strip here to remove the `\n` imported, you may not need this if there are no new lines in your file.

```
with open('first-names.txt', 'r')as f:
    d = set(f.readlines())

with open('oliver-twist.txt', 'r') as f:
    e = set(f.readlines())

result = [name.strip() for name in d for sentence in e if name.strip() in sentence]

#['Abram', 'Ada', 'Adah', 'Bill', 'Adam']
```

I added all names to `oliver-twist.txt` and `bill` to `first-names.txt` as there were no matches in the sample.