# Python: Find exact matching words from 2+ txt files files

Tags: python

```
data1 = open("a.txt", 'r').readline().strip().split(',')
data2 = open("b.txt", 'r').readline().strip().split(',')
res = list((set(data1) - set(data2)).union(set(data2) - set(data1)))
```

how can I do the above but with multiple txt files? they are comma seperated, and in lines. I want to find matching words given data1.

data1 == data2

data1 == data3

data1 == data4

...

From:[compare two file and find matching words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355137/compare-two-file-and-find-matching-words-in-python)

```
with open("file1") as f1,open("file2") as f2:
    words=set(line.strip() for line in f1)   #create a set of words from dictionary file

    #why sets? sets provide an O(1) lookup, so overall complexity is O(N)

    #now loop over each line of other file (word, freq file)
    for line in f2:
        word,freq=line.split()   #fetch word,freq 
        if word in words:        #if word is found in words set then print it
            print word
output the same words found in both files:

apple
```

The output in my case should be words found in those files that are also found in data1...
any idea is much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you already doing this with multiple text files?

Comment: No, that is between two  (data1 and data2), I want one single code which considers 5 txt files (data2, data3, data4, data5) and match with the target (data1)

Comment: Can you show an example (maybe with only 3 files)? What exactly should be the result?

Comment: Okay, I took a snippet from an example from elsewhere, the output should be the words that are the same, idk how to go on about adding more files to the code which is what I need help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you already have does pretty much everything you want. I couldn't understand exactly what you wanted but I guessed one of two things

1. You want the words present in data1 & data2, data1 & data3, data1 & data4

   For this, you can store the words in a single list instead of printing them and run the same loop for all multiple files
2. You want the words present in data1 & data2 & data3 & data4
   For this, you can store the words for each, but in separate lists, and get the intersection of these lists (you can use a list of lists here for convenience)

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I did end up doing the first one! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you out!